# How to make angular components full screen with the actual size of the windows

Tags: css, angular

I am working with angular and in my app.component.html i have some component like so :

```
<app-selector1></app-selector1>
<app-selector2></app-selector2>
...
```

I am wondering how I could make my component full screen with css (100%width & height of the actual window size)
With all my try I always still have a little space something like a margin/padding but the inspector told me that they were at 0 each.

I tried some things and this one:

```
body div {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `css` you will find two units perfect for what you want:

`vh` for viewport-height -> as a percentage of the full height of your device screen

`vw` for viewport-width-> as a percentage of the full width of your device screen

So if you want the full height of your screen so 100% of it you can achieve it using `height: 100vh`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you wanted only 60% of the height just use `height: 60vh` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vh as unit for height and vw for width.

```
body div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Check it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp