# Vue background color for a single view

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vue + Vuetify.

I want to alternate the color of the background in a single view file. I tried using

```
    <section
      id="protocol"
      class="ivory"
      >
      ...
      ..
      .
    </section>
```

for each section in the view file, but this doesn't fill the background color full width.
How can I properly alternate the color of each section in a single `View.vue` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `css`, you can use this

`vh` for viewport-height -> as a percentage of the full height of your device screen

`vw` for viewport-width-> as a percentage of the full width of your device screen

So if you want the full height of your screen so 100% of it you can achieve it using `height: 100vh`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

credit for answer: [johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60260890/16481300)